# Java's Regular Expression don't recognize characters from other languages as word characters (i.e \w)

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Lets say I have a word: "Aiavärav". The expression `\w+` should capture this word, but the letter "ä" cuts the word in half. Instead of "Aiavärav", I get "Aia". What is the correct regex for words that contain those non-ascii letters?

Comment: I copied your word and put into string, I used regular expression \w+ and I can get word correctly. I am testing with C#.

Comment: Im using Java. Also i have tested with myregextester.com and still it doesnt recognize whole word.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [Unicode letters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)? `\p{L}+`

Comment: Yes, I go that site and test. Cannot get correct result. I tested my C# code again. I got word as expected. 
            string test = "Aiavärav abc 123";
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w+");
            Console.Write(reg.Match(test)); I got "Aiavärav"

Comment: corrected "non-latin" since "ä" is still technically a latin-derived character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\w` only matches `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` unless you specify the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag:

```
Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
```

or embed a `(?U)` in the pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("(?U)\\w+")
```

either of which requires JDK 1.7 (i.e., Java 7).

If you don't have Java 7, you can generalize `\w` to Unicode by using `\p{L}` ("letter"; like `[a-zA-Z]`, but not ASCII-specific) and `\p{N}` ("number"; like `[0-9]`, but not ASCII-specific):

```
Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}_\\p{N}]+")
```

But it sounds like maybe you're looking for actual *words*, in the normal sense (as opposed to the programming-language sense), and don't need to support digits and underscores? In that case, you can just use `\p{L}`:

```
Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+")
```

(By the way, the curly brackets are actually optional — you can write `\pL` instead of `p{L}` and `\pN` instead of `\p{N}` — but people usually include them anyway, because they're required for multi-letter categories like `\p{Lu}` "uppercase letter".)

Comment: Be aware that embedding (?U) "... may impose a performance penalty." from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS

Comment: @niconic: The documentation that you link to is actually referring to `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` rather than `(?U)`, but either way, I think the expensive part is matching using Unicode character properties (compared to the groups of ASCII characters). Since that is exactly what the OP is trying to do, it's not really a "performance penalty" in his/her case, and would presumably apply to *any* approach (s)he might take.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but in the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` link i read also `The UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?U). `, so I think that we're talking about the same stuff. Am I misunderstanding something? Of course your answer fits the need, I just wanted to point out that (because I found myself in a vaguely similar case and performance for me was essential)

Comment: @niconic: The documentation states that this *mode* can be enabled via `(?U)`, but the statement that the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` *flag* may impose a performance penalty is in a separate paragraph, so does not apply to `(?U)`. To be sure, I believe the same statement could be made of `(?U)`; but my concern about your comment is that my answer names three approaches, and your comment says that *one* of them may impose a performance penalty, as though you were advocating the other two approaches instead. That's highly misleading, since (I believe) *every* approach has the same penalty.

Comment: Ok I got, my comment could be misleading: when I wrote it I didn't want to target precisely the ?U flag but what it means (i.e. all approaches).